# adding active class to top level menu of a submenu

Tags: jquery, html, css, menu

I am using a nav menu in my project.The menu has several menu which again has sub-menu and mega menu.I am trying to add class to the active link menu.I have succeeded to do that but i also want to add the `active` class to the main menu of the correnponding submenu
Take a look at below markup

```
<ul class="nav-menu">
   <li>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="zoo.php">zoozo</a></li>
         <li><a href="about">Abort</a></li>
         <li><a href="connect">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

### My js

```
$(".nav-menu li a").filter(function(){
   return this.href == location.href.replace(/#.*/, "");
}).addClass("active");
```

this is adding `active` class to the `zoo.php` or other link but i also want to add `active` class to `Home` -> `<a href="#" class="active">Home</a>` like this
.
Any one can help?

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way (http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/h092n82y/):

```
$('.nav-menu li a:eq(0)').addClass('active');
```

But better way — to use classes for matching in Javascript:

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="nav-menu">
   <li>
      <a class="js-home-link" href="#">Home</a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href="zoo.php">zoozo</a></li>
         <li><a href="about">Abort</a></li>
         <li><a href="connect">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$('.js-home-link').addClass('active');
```

Comment: no but you have to think about there is not only one menu.there is more than one main menu and they have several sub menu :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".nav-menu li a").filter(function(){
   return this.href == location.href.replace(/#.*/, "");
})
.addClass("active")
.closest('ul')
.prev('a')
.addClass("active");
```